# How do I get the var and value for a selected dropdown menu item in a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a dropdown menu in a form labeled "Gender" with options for "Male" and "Female". I don't know how to enter the var and value line. I am using it in a form that will be emailed so I need whatever choice the person selects to show in the email.

HTML

```html
<select name="Gender" id="gender">
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
```

PHP

```php
$sentMail = mail($to_Email, "Insurance Verification", $_POST["userFirstName"]." ".$_POST["userMiddleName"]." ".$_POST["userLastName"]." ".$_POST["userDate"]." ". $_POST["userGender"]." ".$_POST["userMember"]." ".$_POST["userInsurance"], $headers);
```

JS

```javascript
var user_firstname  = $('input[name=firstname]').val()
var user_middlename = $('input[name=middlename]').val()
var user_lastname   = $('input[name=lastname]').val()
var user_email      = $('input[name=email]').val()
var user_date       = $('input[name=date]').val()
var selectedVal     = $('#gender option:selected').val('male, female')
var user_member     = $('input[name=member]').val()
var user_insurance  = $('input[name=insurance]').val()

//data to be sent to server
post_data = {'userFirstName':user_firstname, 'userMiddleName':user_middlename, 'userLastName':user_lastname, 'userEmail':user_email, 'userGender':selectedVal, 'userMember':user_member, 'userInsurance':user_insurance, 'userDate':user_date}
```

Answer (score 0):

If its just an html form, you use

```
<select name="gender">
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use jQuery with `select`, and you want to extract the selected value, you can simple use this:

```
var gender = $("#gender").val();
```

And you can retrieve the selected value. :)